# c# EF tables having one to many relation - display on same page

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have classes like:

```
public class Parent
{
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        .....
        public virtual ICollection<ChildValue>ChildValues { get; set; }
}

public class ChildValue
{
        public int ChildValueValueId { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Parent Parent{ get; set; }
}
```

in the controller class I have:

```
public ViewResult DisplayData(*Searchvalue*)
{
       Parent parent = DbContext.Parent
                    .Where(x => (..) && (..)).FirstOrDefault();
       return View(parent);    
}
```

My question is: in controller class DisplayData function, when i do debug and quick watch parent.ChildValues why it is null? I thought EF will automatically retrieve the related child values and on view page i can display that using foreach loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you says "when I do parent.ChildValues", you mean you do this while you are stepping over code in Visual studio, or do you mean when you are rendering the data on the view?

Comment: @PreetSingh: when debuging - stepping over the code

Comment: Are there any child Values in the DB at all?

Comment: @PreetSingh: ya it has more than 20 records

Comment: Is LazyLoading Switched on in your DBContext Config?

Comment: i guess by default it is ON. in my DBContext class constructor i have        var ensureDLLIsCopied = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Comment: ok. in DBContext constructor i set this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled  to true. it's working now.

Comment: Thanks @PreetSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled is set to false, DbContext will not load child objects for some parent object unless  [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx) method is called on parent object. Setting `DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` to true or false will have no impact on its behaviours.

Also in the view, In order to display your Child Entities make sure you do not dispose off the DbContext, Till the View is fully rendered or Response is gone out.